# Why doesn't integration of the wavefunction squared give 1 for rigid rotors?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, schroedinger-equation, normalization

[This source](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Quantum_States_of_Atoms_and_Molecules_(Zielinksi_et_al.)/07%3A_Rotational_States/7.03%3A_Solving_the_Rigid_Rotor_Schr%C3%B6dinger_Equation) states that the wavefunction for rigid rotors for a *constant* radius $R$ is:
$$\psi(\theta,\phi)=\Theta(\theta)\cdot \Phi(\phi)$$ 
Integrating $\psi(\theta,\phi)^2$ over $d\theta$ and $d\phi$ must equal $1$.

Therefore, integrating $\Theta(\theta)^2$ up to $\pi$ and $\Phi(\phi)\cdot\Phi(\phi)^*$ up to $2\pi$ must also each equal $1$. This is also what the source is stating by explaining that they need to be normalized (e.g. Equation $7.3.12$).

However, integrating any of the Associated Legendre Functions of $\Theta(\theta)$ shown in Table $7.3.1$ (third column) when squared, does *not* give $1$. 
Even though it is clearly stated in the text above the Table that they include the normalization constants.

Why does integration of these functions squared not give $1$?

Comment: did you think to include the $\sin\theta$ factor when integrating over the $\theta$'s, i.e. the differential is $\sin\theta\,d\theta$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Shouldn't that already be taken into account if the functions are already normalized as stated?

Comment: It is not.  You also need the factors if you are to explicitly verify that the spherical harmonics (for instance) are orthogonal.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Ok got it, but what are the functions normalized to then?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your point.  For instance the spherical harmonics are normalized to $\int d\Omega \vert Y^\ell_m(\theta,\varphi)\vert^2=1$ with $d\Omega =\sin\theta d\theta d\varphi$.

Comment: Nvm, I figured that part out. Since the square of $Y^\ell_m(\theta,\varphi)$ integrated over $d\Omega$ gives the probability density (integration gives $1$), doesn't this mean that $Y^\ell_m(\theta,\varphi)$ is actually the wavefunction $\psi$? Because it is the product of both functions $\Phi(\varphi) \cdot \Theta(\theta)$ exactly like how $\psi$ is defined according to equation $7.3.1$.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.  The spherical harmonics are products and the spherical volume element is still $\sin\theta d\theta\,d\varphi$.  The fact that spherical harmonics are products doesn't enter into this. Maybe I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Sorry I'm not talking about the integration anymore. All I'm asking is if $$Y^\ell_m(\theta,\varphi) = \psi(\theta, \varphi)$$ Based on equation $7.3.1$

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Is this correct?

Comment: Well...  It depends how technical you want to be.  Yes the spherical harmonics are those functions but it turns out the rigid-rotor wavefunctions are usually expressed in terms of $D$ functions.  The spherical harmonic would apply to spherical rotor, with 3 identical moments of inertia.  The best I could find is Eq.(6.43) of:  https://books.google.ca/books?id=r4cNOM1iB68C&pg=PA349&lpg=PA349&dq=symmetric+top+D-functions&source=bl&ots=BOHknSbcYx&sig=ACfU3U37zWy3zbBw5xx5U071kKHjfT6EMg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4tZLgkd_oAhXTKM0KHbYSC14Q6AEwBXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=symmetric%20top%20D-functions&f=false

Comment: There is lots of good stuff on rigid rotors in nuclear physics text.  Bohr& Mottelson or Landau&Lifschitz (QM) come to mind but are not the only ones. Many nuclei are deformed in their ground state and so behave like rotors, so nuclear physicist have discussed this topic at length.  I’m afraid the subtleties involves if one is interested in the wavefunctions and not the energies are not stuff covered in all elementary courses.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the integral of a function $f(\theta, \phi)$ over angles on the sphere is 
$$\int_0^\pi d \theta \, \sin \theta \int_0^{2 \pi} d \phi \, f(\theta, \phi).$$
The presence of the $\sin \theta$ factor is explained in standard multivariable calculus courses.